# update @HostBinding Angular 4 Animation

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I am trying to get animation between routes working in an Angular 4 project - but need to be able to alter the direction of the animation (translateX) based on the way the user is navigating through the app.

I have discovered that the only way to keep both the entering and exiting components in the DOM is to use void state.

Also, I have to bind the animation to the host element. If I try and bind it to an element within the component the exiting component is just replaced with the entering component.

I want this because I don't want the exiting component to disappear - I want it to slide off as the entering component slides in to get a smooth native feeling application.

I have a single trigger set up with four transitions:

```
trigger('routing',[
    state('*',style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
    transition('void => back',[
        style({transform: 'translateX(-100%'}),
        animate('800ms')
    ]),
    transition('back => void',[
        animate('800ms',style({
            transform:'translateX(100%)'
        }))
    ]),
    transition('void => forward',[
        style({transform: 'translateX(100%'}),
        animate('800ms')
    ]),
    transition('forward => void',[
        animate('800ms',style({
            transform:'translateX(-100%)'
        }))
    ])
])
```

In my components exported class I am binding this to the component host elements with:

```
@HostBinding('@routing') routing
```

I can manipulate `routing` (setting it to either 'back' or 'forward' to control direction) but this seems to create a new instance of the variable so that if I want to change animation direction the exiting page animates in the opposite direction to the incoming component because the instance of `routing` doesn't seem to have changed.

**Is there any way to update the instance of `routing` bound to the host element? Is there an alternative way to achieve the result I need?**

Thanks.

Comment: Got this working in the end with the help of a friend. Working example here:  https://github.com/claytonF/NG4-route-anim